# Mismatch between Point Projection and Warped 2-D Image [opencv]

Tags: c++, image, opencv, 3d

I am using 2 different methods to render an image (as an opencv Matrix):

1. an implemented projection function that uses the camera intrinsics (focal length, principal point; distortion is disabled) - this function is used in other software packages and is supposed to work correctly ([repository](https://github.com/ethz-asl/okvis/tree/master/okvis_cv/include/okvis/cameras))
2. a 2D to 2D image warping (here, I'm determining the intersections of the corner-rays of my camera with my 2D image that should be warped into my camera frame); this backprojection of the corner points is using the same camera model as above

Now, I overlay these two images and what should basically happen is that a projected pen-tip (method 1.) should line up with a line that is drawn on the warped image (method 2.). However, this is not happening.

There is a tiny shift in both directions, depending on the orientation of the pen that is writing, and it is reduced when I am shifting the principal point of the camera. Now my question is, since I am not considering the principal point in the 2D-2D image warping, can this be the cause of the mismatch? Or is it generally impossible to align those two, since the image warping is a simplification of the projection process?

[image]

- Grey Point: projected origin (should fall in line with the edges of the white area)
- Blue Reticle: penTip that should "write" the Bordeaux-colored line
- Grey Line: pen approximation
- Red Edge: "x-axis" of white image part
- Green Edge: "y-axis" of white image part

EDIT:

I also did the same projection with the origin of the coordinate system, and here, the mismatch grows, the further the origin moves out of the center of the image. (so `delta[warp,project]` gets larger on the image borders compare to the center)

Comment: Please add some images to clarify.

Comment: With OpenCV (and the pinhole camera model AFAIK) considers the principal point to be in the middle of the image, or better said, having the origin in the top left corner, they use the cx and cy from the intrinsics to move it to the center (if the cx and cy differs then you may get something out of the center). One possible source of mismatch is the discretization of the projected points. Ceil, round, floor/truncate are possible ways, and if they vary from 2 solutions you will get small differences.

Comment: yes, I thought of discretization errors, but they are getting bigger depending on the location. 
I also thought of proplems going from Eigen to openCV, since of the ordering of columns/rows, and counting direction, but I made sure thats correct (when the camera moves, the points move in the opposite direction, corresponding to their location).